# Not able to use HttpClient in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to make an api call using the HTTPClient in angular 5. and I am getting the below error:

> `DOMException: Failed to set the 'responseType' property on 'XMLHttpRequest': The response type cannot be changed for synchronous requests made from a document.
>       at Observable._subscribe (http://cw.local/assets/js/dist/cw.angular.min.1522911179.js:229447:34)
>       at Observable._trySubscribe (http://cw.local/assets/js/dist/cw.angular.min.1522911179.js:19762:25)
>       at Observable.subscribe (http://cw.local/assets/js/dist/cw.angular.min.1522911179.js:19750:93)
>       at Object.subscribeToResult (http://cw.local/assets/js/dist/cw.angular.min.1522911179.js:24782:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://cw.local/assets/js/dist/cw.angular.min.1522911179.js:50664:38)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://cw.local/assets/js/dist/cw.angular.min.1522911179.js:50661:14)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://cw.local/assets/js/dist/cw.angular.min.1522911179.js:50644:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://cw.local/assets/js/dist/cw.angular.min.1522911179.js:24556:18)
>       at ScalarObservable._subscribe (http://cw.local/assets/js/dist/cw.angular.min.1522911179.js:55704:24)
>       at ScalarObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (http://cw.local/assets/js/dist/cw.angular.min.1522911179.js:19762:25)`

The code is very basic. However, just to mention this is a Hybrid app which is using NgUpgrade module.

> angularjs version 1.5.x angular version 5.1.3

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {MyService} from "./my-service";
@Injectable()
export default class ResultsService {
   constructor( private http: HttpClient, private service: MyService) {
}
   purchaseByExtractId(extractId, address) {
       let payload = {
           session_key: key,
           admin_district: address
       };

       return this.http.post(this.service.getUrl(), {postData: payload}).toPromise();
   }

   purchaseExtractSummary(key) {
      return this.http.post(this.service.getUrl(), {postData: {session_key: key}}).toPromise();
   }
}
```

Edit: I have tried removing the toPromise and subscribing also. It still fails with the same error

Comment: `synchronous requests`? Synchronous requests are deprecated since ages... Are you sure the problem comes from angular 5 httpClient?

Comment: Yep, I know. I am not setting that explicitly. I believe somehow the hybrid nature of the app is causing this.

Comment: I had this exact issue and the problem I had was one of the js assets i included in `angular.json` making a synchronous request. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone else's benefit I'm answering my own question here.
The reason was what Onikute has mentioned in one of the comments to original post. I had a tracking library included on the page which was making synchronous calls and was messing up with the angular HTTP requests. Had figured this out a while back but had forgotten to update the answer. 
Thanks Onikute for reminding.

Comment: How did you fix it thought? Did you get rid of the tracking library or did you do some workaround?

Comment: man, you saved me a lot of time. My problem was with TikTok pixel

Comment: @HaseebAhmed too late to answer, but i moved all the tracking code outside of the main app

Answer (score 1):

1) did you add import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'; ?

2) what is response from this.service.getUrl() ?

3) Did you import to your module:

`import { HttpsRequestInterceptor } from './services/http.interceptor';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';`

4) Did you add to `providers` :
`{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpsRequestInterceptor, multi: true },` ?

5) Did you add to `imports`: `HttpClientModule` ?

6) Did you use interceptor correctly?

this is an example of http.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class HttpsRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private actionUrl: string;

    constructor(
    ) {
        this.actionUrl = 'https://example.com/';
    }


    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const _req = {
            url: this.actionUrl + req.url,
            headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        };

        return next.handle(req.clone(_req));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: 1) Why would that work? I have tried without toPromise, still doesn't work.

2). It returns a json

Comment: I have tried that as well and it did not work. Have updated the question

Comment: Yes. I am not able to use the HttpClient at all. Meanwhile I have created a jQuery wrapper to make api calls using jQuery.ajax.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, however, I haven't used interceptors in my app. I was trying to get it to work correctly. I will try and set up a minimal reproducible plunkr when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
purchaseByExtractId(key: string, address: string) {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify({ session_key: key, admin_district: address });
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
        return this.http.post<any>(this.service.getUrl(), bodyString, { headers: headers });
```